# Running another run inside my app in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an app run another app inside my app like virtualbox but it not working there is any way can I create this type application?

```
try {
            // Path to the APK file of the target app
            String apkPath = "/sdcard/test/base.apk";

            // Path to the directory where you want to store the optimized DEX file
            String optimizedDir = getDir("dex", 0).getAbsolutePath();

            // Create DexClassLoader
            DexClassLoader dexClassLoader = new DexClassLoader(apkPath, optimizedDir, null, getClass().getClassLoader());

            // Load the class dynamically
            String className = "com.csdroid.pkg.MainActivity";
            Class<?> loadedClass = dexClassLoader.loadClass(className);

            
            // Create an instance of the loaded class
            Object mainActivityInstance = loadedClass.newInstance();

            // Get the method to call
            Method startActivityMethod = loadedClass.getDeclaredMethod("onCreate", Bundle.class);
            
            // Set the method's accessibility to true
            startActivityMethod.setAccessible(true);
            
            // Invoke the method to start the activity
            startActivityMethod.invoke(mainActivityInstance, new Bundle());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof InvocationTargetException && e.getCause() != null) {
                tv1.setText("Error caues: " + e.getCause().toString());
            } else {
                tv1.setText("Error: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
```

there is any way can I create this type app without using 3rd party library